# Looping in R through databases to get the table schema in sql and show the output in R

Tags: sql, r

I'm new to both R and SQL. The program I'm writing is in R language, and it is supposed to get the table schema or table description of all the tables which are there in approx 34 databases; the name of databases starts with RM_%. I'm doing this using RODBC package in R language; I have taken the list of all the databases in list of R language using the following command :

```
listOfRMSDatabase <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases where name like 'RM_%'")
```

And the command in sql to get the schema is

```
SELECT * 
FROM database_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

I'm thinking to do it loop in R, so that every time the new database would be give the result and can be saved and appended or shown separately , but I'm not sure how to do this in the loop, do I need to save the data in dataframe, can somebody advice and help me in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please describe an expected output. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. You are stating 'I have taken list of all databases'.. but in your query you are filtering only those that contain R?

Comment: Also.. what kind of difference are you trying to detect? A new database added on the server? A new column in the existing databases? Please explain in further detail.

Comment: @Prometheus.. the expected o/p should show the table schema/ table description of all the tables of all the databases that starts with R%, i.e. the name of the database should start with R only.Actually there are other databases also, but I don't want them. Moreover, The databases are already there on the server, I just want to see the schema of the tables of all the databases group by tables. Through loop in R I want to read each database in the list and get the its table schema and may be append the result and display it. I hope now it makes sense.